# Context Setting for virtual host in Tomcat 7

Tags: tomcat7, virtualhost

I like to access my website [http://www.mysite.com/my-web-site] using [http://www.mysite.com]

I have defined a **Host** in /conf/server.xml as follows

```
<Host name="www.mysite.com" appBase="lpsadmin" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true" copyXML="true" />
```

In my **my-web-site.war** I have context.xml under META-INF which has the following

```
<Context path="" docBase="/my-web-site" reloadable="true" allowLinking="true" cacheMaxSize="40960"/>
```

From Tomcat documentation I know docBase will not be honoured when **Host** has an appBase.  As expected, I get the following warning

```
WARNING: A docBase /Applications/tomcatstack-7.0.32-0/apache-tomcat/lpsadmin/my-web-site inside the host appBase has been specified, and will be ignored
```

How do I change my context path when **Host** has an **appBase**? I do not prefer ROOT.xml solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find ways to achieve this without ROOT.xml.  I have achieved this by placing a **httpd** in front of Tomcat and added virtual hosts in httpd.